# Calculating bond duration and price change when yield changes

Tags: bonds, yield, duration

I've been working on this forever and I'm still not sure if my answers are correct. My question is:

A 10 year bond with a face value of $1000 paying semi-annual 7% coupon. Bond is paying 7% YTM.
Calculate the duration of the bond - which I have done and come up with 7.36 years.

On solving this and adding up the PV of the cash flows I got a current bond price of $1008.43 and not sure if this is correct?? and why it is over $1000?

I need the correct current bond price to calculate the next question which is: using the duration approach estimate the price change when yield increases from 7% to 8% per year, 7% to 9% per year and 7% to 10 per cent per year. I keep getting different answers and it is driving me nuts.
Would appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: For the PV, use a discount rate of 3.5% and discount by the number of coupons, not years. That should get you 1,000 exactly. Your duration is pretty close to what I get (7.3549) and should be exact once you fix the PV. Show your calculatoins for the last step so we can see where you're off.

Comment: Thank you that is super helpful. Got it now